# Installing mpyfit ("error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1")

Tags: python, anaconda

When installing the Python package [mpyfit](https://github.com/evertrol/mpyfit), I receive the following error:

```
"error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1"
```

Information:

- Python Version: 2.7.8
- Environment: Anaconda
- Machine: Windows 8.1

Here is the Traceback:

```
C:\Users\Roger\Anaconda\pkgs\mpyfit>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing mpyfit.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to mpyfit.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to mpyfit.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'mpyfit.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'mpyfit.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'mpyfit.mpfit' extension
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -Impyfit/cmpfit -IC:\Users\Roger\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\U
sers\Roger\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\Roger\Anaconda\PC -c mpyfit/mpyfit.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o -std
=c99 -Wno-declaration-after-statement -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_9_API_VERSION
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -Impyfit/cmpfit -IC:\Users\Roger\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\U
sers\Roger\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\Roger\Anaconda\PC -c mpyfit/cmpfit/mpfit.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\cmpfit\
mpfit.o -std=c99 -Wno-declaration-after-statement -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_9_API_VERSION
writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpfit.def
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\
cmpfit\mpfit.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpfit.def -LC:\Users\Roger\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Users\Roger\Anaconda\PCbuild\am
d64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\mpyfit\mpfit.pyd
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_InitModule4_64'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_ImportModule'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCObject_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCObject_AsVoidPtr'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x188): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x1de): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Print'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x223): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_Size'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x25f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs'

build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs'

build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x2ce): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x309): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x311): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x452): undefined reference to `_imp__PyList_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x45c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x482): undefined reference to `_imp__PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x499): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCallable_Check'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x4ad): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x4b5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x50a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x512): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x539): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x541): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x5b2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyList_Size'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x5e1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x5e9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x66c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x674): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x6a0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBool_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x6ac): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_TrueStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x6b8): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x6c4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x6e6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyList_GetItem'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x75c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x764): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x799): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x7b8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x7c0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x803): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x826): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x82e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x840): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_Size'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x857): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x85f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x875): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_GetItem'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x889): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x891): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x8ab): undefined reference to `_imp__PyNumber_Float'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x8c5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x8cd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x8df): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Restore'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x8ee): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x8f7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x90b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x913): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x92b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_GetItem'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x93f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x947): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x961): undefined reference to `_imp__PyNumber_Float'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x977): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x97f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x991): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Restore'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x99a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x9a3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x9b7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x9bf): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x9d8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x9ed): undefined reference to `_imp__PyNumber_Float'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa03): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa3b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Restore'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa44): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa4d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa61): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa69): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xa9e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xab3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyNumber_Float'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xac9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xad1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb01): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Restore'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb0a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb13): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb27): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb2f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb64): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb83): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xb8b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xbcf): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xbf7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xc0b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xc13): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xc48): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Restore'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xc51): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xc5a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xc6e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xc76): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xcab): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xcd3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xce7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xcef): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xd24): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Restore'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xd2d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xd36): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xd4a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xd52): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xe46): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xe4e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xfec): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0xff4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x1047): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x11af): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_BuildValue'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x12a4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\mpyfit\mpyfit.o:mpyfit.c:(.text+0x12ac): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried installing mpyfit with pip using

```
pip install github.com/evertrol/mpyfit/archive/master.zip
```

but that did not work either and returned the same error...

How can I solve this issue? Please let me know if I need to provide additional information.